# BatchInserter initialization yields ArrayIndexOutOfBounds and ExceptionInInitializationError

Tags: neo4j

All I'm trying to do is the following:

```
    BatchInserter ins = BatchInserters.inserter("target/batchinserter-example");
```

where `"target/batchinserter-example"` is a given store directory. It compiles fine, but I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.rejectAutoUpgrade(BatchInserterImpl.java:556)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.<init>(BatchInserterImpl.java:219)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:94)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:51)
    at NeoBatchInserter.main(NeoBatchInserter.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings.<clinit>(GraphDatabaseSettings.java:69)
    ... 7 more
```

I don't understand how this isn't working.  I'm literally just calling a constructor that takes a `String`.  I'm quite frustrated at the moment. If there is a better way to do this, I am welcome to trying it.  All I want to do is set up a `BatchInserter` (from scratch) so that I can begin my work.

**EDIT**:
I just attempted to point it a `graph.db` from a test graph, and this still didn't work...

I'm also using kernel.2.1.3

**EDIT 2**:
Since my server is 2.1.2, I changed my jars to the 2.1.2 version, yet I still get the same error.

Comment: can you find the missing parts of the exception trace? esp. what GraphDatabaseSettings fails on? Perhaps you can debug to that line?

Comment: Looks like you have no caches loaded, so it seems like a classpath error that makes Neo4j not finding the cache-providers (could also be a version issue)? How do you configure your project? maven, gradle?

Comment: @MichaelHunger I'm not using anything to configure the project--straight up manual linkage.  Should I be using maven?

Comment: @MichaelHunger Thanks, using maven got everything to work!

Answer (score 1):

What version of Neo4j was the directory created with? I'm pretty sure that you cannot use batchinserter of 2.1.3 with an earlier version.

Install 2.1.3, set `allow_store_upgrade=true` in neo4j.properties, start the server and shut it down. It's crucial to have a clean shutdown. Then use your batchinserter code.

Comment: From what I can tell, one should simply be able to give any string as a parameter and it should create the store, no?

Comment: I'm using neo4j 2.1.2 server, but I didn't think that from that line of code, there would be a connected with the server.  Is this not the case?

Comment: Tried the stop and start/restart/etc, didn't do anything... Changed to 2.1.2 jar same error.  Changed to 2.1.3 server, same error.  Does this code actually work?  I literally reinstalled everything and nothing changed.

Comment: are you really sure you've done a clean shutdown, e.g. using `bin/neo4j stop` ?

Comment: The batch-inserter doesn't support updates you have to use either a database of the same version as target or an empty directory.

Comment: I 100% am sure that I used the correct command.  I've used neo4j before, and successfully, I'm just running into issues with this.  I'll try the empty directory approach (thought I did this already, but I'll try again).