# Embedded Neo4j 2.1.6 fails to start in OSGi environment

Tags: neo4j, osgi, apache-servicemix

We're running a modular application plattform using Apache ServiceMix 5.3.0. I need to extend our system with a persistence service - so I want to build an OSGi bundle containing Neo4J 2.1.6.

In my `pom.xml` (Maven) I'm using `maven-bundle-plugin` (org.apache.felix) to build the bundle. I've added nearly every package from `neo4j-kernel` and `neo4j-lucene-index` libs to the `<Export-Package>` section.

When deployed my bundle shows up in "resolved" state. But when beeing started it throws this:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error ...
...
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings.<clinit (GraphDatabaseSettings.java:69)
```

My activator code looks like this (the exception occurs at the last command):

```
  GraphDatabaseFactory factory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
/*      
  ArrayList<CacheProvider> caches = new ArrayList();
  caches.add(new SoftCacheProvider());
  factory.setCacheProviders(caches);
*/      
  GraphDatabaseBuilder builder = factory.newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("neo4j-db");
  graphDb = builder.newGraphDatabase();
```

(It doesn't make a difference if the commented part is active or not.)

The error pattern looks similar like the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331607/batchinserter-initialization-yields-arrayindexoutofbounds-and-exceptionininitial).

I suspect the devil sitting in the following method from `org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings` (line 259f) unable to find any `CacheProvider` instances, although they are packed and referenced in my bundle (`org.neo4j.kernel.impl.cache...`):

```
 private static String[] availableCaches()
 {
    List<String> available = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( CacheProvider cacheProvider : Service.load( CacheProvider.class ) )
    {
        available.add( cacheProvider.getName() );
    }
 ...
    return available.toArray( new String[available.size()] );
 }
```

I believe this is very much an OSGi classloader issue rather than a Neo4J issue. Any ideas how to proceed here?

Comment: Um. You get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in `org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings`... and you think this is an OSGi classloading issue??

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem meanwhile. As Neil already supposed, it was neither an OSGi-issue nor a Neo4J-bug. Instead I had to learn some more lessons about how Neo4J binds its extensions and how to shape OSGi dependencies accordingly in order to get ahead.

These are the results of my yesterday's research:

#### (1) Collect all packages

My mistake was to rely on `maven-bundle-plugin`'s capability to parse the project and automatically break down all internal dependencies to package level (which is neccessary for OSGi). This works perfectly for class relations that are declared by `import` statements, but, of course, will fail where reflection methods are used to bind external stuff.

As the application worked perfectly in my JUnit environment the reasons for my problem had to include missing resources in the OSGi envirmonment.

The solution was to religiously list each single package of every library in the plugins `Export-Package`, `Private-Package` and `Import-Package` section accordingly (the list got quite lengthly) instead of trusting to wildcards.

#### (2) Neo4J kernel extensions

Heeding the above topics I got rid of the mentioned `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` but I right ran into other (similar) exceptions. I got ahead after I learned about Neo4J's "kernel extension" concept.

Neo4J (I have version 2.1.6) has introduced "kernel extensions" to couple exchangeable modules for caching and indexing purpose at runtime. In order to apply a certain extension one just needs to add the according jar to the classpath. Each library carries one or more descriptor files under `META-INF/services` telling about the available implementations. These files are looked up and processed by the kernel in order to find and bind its extensions (extension for indexing and caching are mandatory).

After I securely had all neccessary java packages included in my bundly only the descriptor files in `META-INF/services` were missing. [This code](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/activemq-osgi/5.10.0/activemq-osgi-5.10.0.pom) showed me a way how to add those resources to the bundle (search for the `<Embed-Dependency>` section in the `maven-bundle-plugin`.

Neo4J libs also contain a blueprint descriptor to automatically publish major classes as service (e.g. GraphDatabaseFactory). These resources are placed under `OSGI-INF/blueprint/`, which should also be included in the bundle.

The final `pom.xml` for my Neo4J OSGi bundle looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4jBundle</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  
    <properties>
      <neo4j-version>2.1.6</neo4j-version>
      <lucene-version>3.6.2</lucene-version>
    </properties>
  
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j-version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-lucene-index</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j-version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
          <configuration>
            <instructions>
              <Bundle-Name>org.neo4j.kernel</Bundle-Name>
              <Export-Package>org.neo4j.graphdb.*;version=${neo4j-version},
              ... {all neo4j packages} ...
                org.apache.lucene;version=${lucene-version},
              ... {all lucene packages} ...
                org.slf4j.impl
              </Export-Package>
              <Private-Package>
                javax.transaction,
                javax.transaction.xa,
                ch.qos.logback.classic,
                ... {all logback.classic packages} ...
                ch.qos.logback.core,
                ... {all logback.core packages} ...              
                org.slf4j.*
              </Private-Package>
              <Import-Package>
                javax.lang.model,
                ... {some javax packages to be imported from the runtime} ...
                !sun.misc,
                ... {exclude uneccessary packages to limit dependency} ...
                *
              </Import-Package>
              <Embed-Dependency>
                *;groupId=org.neo4j;artifactId=neo4j-kernel;inline=META-INF/services/*,
                *;groupId=org.neo4j;artifactId=neo4j-kernel;inline=OSGI-INF/blueprint/*,
                *;groupId=org.neo4j;artifactId=neo4j-lucene-index;inline=META-INF/services/*,              
                *;groupId=org.neo4j;artifactId=neo4j-lucene-index;inline=OSGI-INF/blueprint/*              
              </Embed-Dependency>
            </instructions>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </project>
```

Remarks: This is a pure library bundle without any additional code. My application with the Activator resides in a seperate bundle.
This example only shows my aproach in solving my problems. My example doesn't claim to produce a general-purpose Neo4J bundle. Depending on the features you want and the society of already deployed stuff in the runtime you might need to add or leave out certain packages to get everything to work.